# Error While Calculating Home Range Size: Loop 0 is not valid: Edge 0 crosses edge 2

Tags: r

I have a set of lizard tracking data that I'm trying to calculate home range sizes for using MCP, KDE, and AKDE. I have a chunk of code that's suppose to calculate all three estimates at once.

Working example (apologies for the length, smaller subsets did not reproduce the same error):

```r
    library(tidyverse)
    library(janitor)
    library(lubridate)
    library(sp)
    library(sf)
    library(OpenStreetMap)
    library(pbapply)
    library(mgsub)
    library(stringr)
    library(data.table)
    library(terra)
    library(amt)
    library(foreach) 
    library(doParallel)
    library(ctmm)
    X<-c(489755,489792,489537,489505,489322,489323,489535,489532,489646,489649,489393,489254,
    489278,489274,489271,489278,489317,489318,489318,489373,489406,489399,489322,489332,
    489311,489399,489379,489374,489380,489378,489377,489378,489378,489378,489375,489568,
    489574,489570,489547,489424,489424,489424,489461,489147,489176,489633,489544,489702,
    489708,489261,489243,489418,489361,489367,489582,489683,489333,489379,489397,489395,
    489381,489394,489367,489591,489353,489343,489337,489568,489572,489301,489285,489285,
    489164,489245,489242)

    Y<-c(3722898,3722405,3722746,3722467,3722892,3722896,3722744,3722748,3722709,3722709,3722513,
    3722866,3722773,3722766,3722779,3722773,3722749,3722753,3722753,3722703,3722723,3722720,
    3722762,3722755,3722758,3722720,3722741,3722743,3722735,3722738,3722731,3722734,3722736,
    3722736,3722733,3722759,3722754,3722763,3722792,3722811,3722811,3722811,3722796,3722540,
    3722544,3722870,3722810,3722301,3722490,3722472,3722465,3722668,3722899,3722898,3722558,
    3722317,3722769,3722836,3722721,3722722,3722732,3722723,3722895,3723003,3722795,3723039,
    3723038,3722758,3722757,3722838,3722854,3722854,3722808,3722572,3722569)

    timestamp<-c("2004-05-23 15:25:00","2004-05-26 06:29:00","2004-05-30 16:37:00","2004-06-02 18:15:00",
    "2004-06-06 06:50:00","2004-06-09 08:30:00","2004-06-12 05:00:00","2004-06-15 16:48:00",
    "2004-06-19 15:51:00","2004-06-22 10:22:00","2004-06-26 05:13:00","2004-07-07 15:20:00",
    "2004-07-10 10:40:00","2004-07-14 18:22:00","2004-07-17 05:25:00","2004-07-21 17:00:00",
    "2004-07-25 10:29:00","2004-07-29 10:49:00","2004-07-31 19:42:00","2004-08-04 17:29:00",
    "2004-08-11 18:46:00","2004-08-15 18:18:00","2004-08-22 13:37:00","2004-08-25 12:13:00",
    "2004-08-29 06:30:00","2004-09-03 09:42:00","2004-09-08 06:50:00","2004-09-11 10:52:00",
    "2004-09-17 10:37:00","2004-09-21 08:38:00","2004-09-24 07:46:00","2004-10-05 08:27:00",
    "2004-10-07 16:12:00","2004-10-09 14:55:00","2004-10-10 07:58:00","2004-10-16 16:01:00",
    "2004-10-18 08:28:00","2004-10-22 07:40:00","2004-10-25 14:35:00","2004-11-04 08:22:00",
    "2004-11-13 09:22:00","2004-11-21 08:53:00","2004-11-27 12:48:00","2006-03-19 12:45:00",
    "2006-03-26 08:32:00","2006-04-06 13:18:00","2006-04-12 17:13:00","2006-04-24 13:51:00",
    "2006-04-29 11:34:00","2006-05-07 17:56:00","2006-05-19 10:45:00","2006-05-31 11:06:00",
    "2006-06-09 09:31:00","2006-06-16 08:22:00","2006-06-22 10:52:00","2006-06-30 11:14:00",
    "2006-07-10 18:13:00","2006-07-18 17:35:00","2006-07-25 18:48:00","2006-07-28 18:38:00",
    "2006-08-04 10:54:00","2006-08-07 12:15:00","2006-08-14 10:51:00","2006-08-23 10:56:00",
    "2006-09-02 07:10:00","2006-09-07 18:32:00","2006-09-12 11:42:00","2006-09-22 12:35:00",
    "2006-10-03 10:38:00","2006-10-05 09:31:00","2006-10-07 17:50:00","2006-10-17 11:21:00",
    "2006-10-27 12:30:00","2006-11-07 10:25:00","2006-12-02 12:44:00")

    animal.ID<-c("TM01","TM01","TM01","TM01","TM01","TM01","TM01","TM01","TM01","TM01","TM01","TM01",
    "TM01","TM01","TM01","TM01","TM01","TM01","TM01","TM01","TM01","TM01","TM01","TM01",
    "TM01","TM01","TM01","TM01","TM01","TM01","TM01","TM01","TM01","TM01","TM01","TM01",
    "TM01","TM01","TM01","TM01","TM01","TM01","TM01","TM01","TM01","TM01","TM01","TM01",
    "TM01","TM01","TM01","TM01","TM01","TM01","TM01","TM01","TM01","TM01","TM01","TM01",
    "TM01","TM01","TM01","TM01","TM01","TM01","TM01","TM01","TM01","TM01","TM01","TM01",
    "TM01","TM01","TM01")

    year<-c(2004,2004,2004,2004,2004,2004,2004,2004,2004,2004,2004,2004,2004,2004,2004,2004,2004,
    2004,2004,2004,2004,2004,2004,2004,2004,2004,2004,2004,2004,2004,2004,2004,2004,2004,
    2004,2004,2004,2004,2004,2004,2004,2004,2004,2006,2006,2006,2006,2006,2006,2006,2006,
    2006,2006,2006,2006,2006,2006,2006,2006,2006,2006,2006,2006,2006,2006,2006,2006,2006,
    2006,2006,2006,2006,2006,2006,2006)

    data.ex<-data.frame(X,Y,timestamp,animal.ID,year)

    track.ex <- track(data.ex$X, data.ex$Y, data.ex$timestamp, id= data.ex$animal.ID, year= data.ex$year, crs= 4267)
    nest.track.ex <- track.ex %>% filter() %>% nest(data= c(x_, y_, t_))

    nest.amt.ex <- nest.track.ex %>%
    mutate(
    hr_mcp = map(data, hr_mcp),
    hr_kde = map(data, hr_kde),
    hr_akde = map(data, ~ hr_akde(., fit_ctmm(., "auto")))
    )
```

After running the code I get the following error:

Error in `mutate()`:
ℹ In argument: `hr_mcp = map(data, hr_mcp)`.
Caused by error in `map()`:
ℹ In index: 2.
Caused by error in `wk_handle.wk_wkb()`:
! Loop 0 is not valid: Edge 0 crosses edge 2
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.

After playing around, it looks like the error is related to the mcp and akde lines as the kde code works just fine when I run it separately, but I'm not sure how to proceed from there.

Comment: https://github.com/r-spatial/sf/issues/1762 ...  ??

Comment: I tried to use sf_use_s2(FALSE), however this results in another error:                    tpeqd: Invalid latitude (This repeats for all coordinates)
non finite transformation detected:
      coords.x1 coords.x2        
 [1,]    489755   3722898 Inf Inf  (This repeats for all coordinates)                            Error in `mutate()`:
ℹ In argument: `hr_akde = map(data, ~hr_akde(., fit_ctmm(., "auto")))`.
Caused by error in `map()`:
ℹ In index: 1.
Caused by error in `sp::spTransform()`:
! failure in points

Comment: 1:2:3:4:5:6:7:8:9:10:11:12:13:14:15:16:17:18:19:20:21:22:23:24:25:26:27:28:29:30:31:32:33:34:35:36:37:38:39:40:41:42:43
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.                                              (This is the rest of the error)

Comment: Not sure if it'll make a difference, but thought I'd nudge the thread. Anyone have any experience with the amt package that might have an idea of what's going on here?